# How to preprocess and remove noisy data from Landsat-8 image Bands for ndvi time-series analysis

Tags: python, ndvi, landsat-8, cloud-cover

I'm working on satellite image processing, I'm calculating NDVI for time series analysis and vegetation prediction. I'm having a tough time removing the noisy data like,

1. Cloud coverage
2. Haze
3. Cloud shadow

on Landsat-8 satellite image bands.

Is there any way to do this in Python?

I came across [fmask](http://pythonfmask.org/en/latest/) package in python to mask cloud coverage but wasn't clear how to use it.

Then used [pymakser](https://github.com/haoliangyu/pymasker) but was only able to create a separate cloud mask file using BQA band of Landsat-8 but couldn't apply the mask on the image bands.

Finally tried using [rio-cloud mask](https://github.com/mapbox/rio-cloudmask) package but wasn't able to create the pre-requisite top of atmosphere reflectance for landsat-8 bands.

Also it'll be great if there's a method to just use the BQA band of Landsat-8 to remove noisy data from the TIF files using python.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, you might want to take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get accustomed with i.a. the requirements of a question that seeks help in producing code/scripts; most importantly, to aid you in coding people usually want to see at least a minimum of your work and/or research so far. Do you have any code snippets that don´t work, or can refer to some sources you tried to implement maybe? Also, be as specific as you can about the tools/software you intend to use. You can always edit your question to include more information.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for anyone landing here in 2021 or later. Handling the QA masks in Landsat and other remote sensing data is indeed a pain, so I made a small package just for that.

[unpackqa: A python package for QA/QC bit unpacking and labeling in earth science data products](https://pypi.org/project/unpackqa/)

[Full Documentation](https://sdtaylor.github.io/unpackqa/)

Here is a short example, given a numpy array, `img_qa_data` which is the data from a Landsat 8 image QA band, you can create a cloud mask like so:

```
cloud_only_mask = unpackqa.unpack_to_array(img_qa_data, 
                                           product='LANDSAT_8_C2_L2_QAPixel', 
                                           flags=['Cloud'])

plt.imshow(cloud_only_mask, interpolation='none')
```

[image]