# Masking clouds on Landsat8 with Python before NDVI

Tags: python, ndvi, masking, cloudmasking, earthpy

I'm new to remote sensing and trying to mask clouds with Python. I'm using the same method in Earth Data Science website (https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/multispectral-remote-sensing/landsat-in-Python/remove-clouds-from-landsat-data/) I also tried the method in earthpy website and also unpackqa in [How to preprocess and remove noisy data from Landsat-8 image Bands for ndvi time-series analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286417/how-to-preprocess-and-remove-noisy-data-from-landsat-8-image-bands-for-ndvi-time)

I did all of the instructions in the Earth Data Science website with their images. But I couldn't apply to my data. These are the codes like Earth Data Science method:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import rioxarray as rxr
import earthpy as et
import earthpy.plot as ep
import earthpy.spatial as es
import earthpy.mask as em

band_list = os.listdir("C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D/LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1")

path_list = []
for i in band_list:
    path_list.append(os.path.join("C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D/LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1", i))
    
arr_st, meta = es.stack(path_list[6:13], nodata=-9999)
landsat_qa = rxr.open_rasterio(path_list[4], masked=True).squeeze()

high_cloud_confidence = em.pixel_flags["pixel_qa"]["L8"]["High Cloud Confidence"]
cloud = em.pixel_flags["pixel_qa"]["L8"]["Cloud"]
cloud_shadow = em.pixel_flags["pixel_qa"]["L8"]["Cloud Shadow"]
all_masked_values = cloud_shadow + cloud + high_cloud_confidence

cl_mask = landsat_qa.isin(all_masked_values)
np.unique(cl_mask)
cl_mask.plot()
plt.show()
```

I got the left one with my data, however I got the right one with website's data

[image: This is the plot of cl_mask]

[image: However with website's data, I got this:]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
im = ax.imshow(cl_mask, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('tab20b', 2))

cbar = ep.colorbar(im)
cbar.set_ticks((0.25, .75))
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["Clear Pixels", "Cloud / Shadow Pixels"])
ax.set_title("Landsat Cloud Mask | Light Purple Pixels will be Masked")
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

I got the first one with my data, however I got the second one with website's data

[image: This is the plot of clear-cloud pixel]

[image]

```
arr_ma = em.mask_pixels(arr_st, cl_mask)
```

And also I get this error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hilmi\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\hilmi\desktop\2204-d\untitled0.py", line 73, in <module>
    arr_ma = em.mask_pixels(arr_st, cl_mask)

  File "C:\Users\hilmi\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\earthpy\mask.py", line 250, in mask_pixels
    return _apply_mask(arr, cover_mask)

  File "C:\Users\hilmi\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\earthpy\mask.py", line 161, in _apply_mask
    raise ValueError("Mask requires values of 1 (True) to be applied.")

ValueError: Mask requires values of 1 (True) to be applied.
```

Also I tried unpackqa.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import rioxarray as rxr
import earthpy as et
import earthpy.plot as ep
import earthpy.spatial as es
import earthpy.mask as em
import unpackqa

band_list = os.listdir("C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D/LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1")

path_list = []
for i in band_list:
    path_list.append(os.path.join("C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D/LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1", i))
    
arr_st, meta = es.stack(path_list[6:13], nodata=-9999)
landsat_qa = rxr.open_rasterio(path_list[4], masked=True).squeeze()

cloud_only_mask = unpackqa.unpack_to_array(np.asarray(landsat_qa, dtype=int), 
                                           product='LANDSAT_8_C2_L2_QAPixel', 
                                           flags=['Cloud'])

ma_b4 = em.mask_pixels(arr_st[3], cloud_only_mask)
ma_b5 = em.mask_pixels(arr_st[4], cloud_only_mask)

ndvi = es.normalized_diff(ma_b5, ma_b4)
ep.plot_bands(ndvi, cmap="RdYlGn")
plt.show()
```

And I got this strange ndvi plot

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Where am I doing wrong?

Also is there any other solutions to mask clouds with Python?

Comment: Can you print out the `path_list` variable and see if the position 4 is actually the PIXEL_QA band?

Comment: Yes @Shawn, when I print out I got this: `In [3]:path_list[4]
Out[3]: 'C:/Users/hilmi/Desktop/2204-D/LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1\\LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1_QA_PIXEL.TIF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded this image and found two things that are likely throwing you off. The 1st is you must scale the band 4 and 5 data by the scaling factor and offset (see here https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-do-i-use-scale-factor-landsat-level-2-science-products).
The 2nd is there is still a handful of weird values inside this Landsat 8 image which is causing very large NDVI values, even after scaling. Thus make sure to set the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments when you use the plotting features. Here is some code which does not use earthpy, so as to take out some of the complexity.

```
import rasterio
import unpackqa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with rasterio.open('./LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1_QA_PIXEL.TIF') as src:
    qa_data = src.read(1)

cloud_only_mask = unpackqa.unpack_to_array(qa_data, 
                                           product='LANDSAT_8_C2_L2_QAPixel', 
                                           flags=['Cloud'])

with rasterio.open('./LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF') as src:
    b4_data = src.read(1)
    
with rasterio.open('./LC08_L2SP_119018_20210303_20210312_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF') as src:
    b5_data = src.read(1)

# Scale surface reflectance
b4_data = (b4_data * 0.0000275) + -0.2
b5_data = (b5_data * 0.0000275) + -0.2

ndvi = (b5_data - b4_data) / (b5_data + b4_data)
ndvi_masked = np.ma.masked_array(ndvi, mask=cloud_only_mask)

plt.imshow(ndvi_masked, interpolation='none', vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

And the resulting image. Also note there are very few clouds in this image.

[image]

Comment: I also worked on images that have low cloud cover and calculated ndvi, but I was getting strange mean variables. That's worked for me. , i didnt scale them. Thank you :)